# Constrained generic type return value needs to relate to argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm relatively new to TypeScript and I've stumbled on a concept that I struggle to understand. [Example - Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4ChnID2IEAXMiAK4C2ARtANz7JgDuh5VdjuAvrrjABPAA4oAogA841EQBsIAMUogEYYMWQBeZAB4AKsgiTIIACYY0mCAD4AFHCgBzDOX0BKbTeTYA2gGsIIWRQZEChQhhkfQBdNwCgmN4mXARiDDAjaVkFZVVyKRl5JRU1DRBtZAdnTy1vPAIoCDBKKAqGgiISckcnADpiCAAaZgI2DmRevvGRgn5%20IA):

```
interface Base {
  one: number;
  two: number;
}

type ExampleFunction = <T extends Base>(args: T) => {[key in keyof T]: T[key]};

const exampleFunction: ExampleFunction = (arg) => {
  return { <-- this object throws an error
    one: arg.one,
    two: arg.two,
  }
}
```

As far as I understand it, I contain the generic to an object with two key-value-pairs. However, if I try to return an object with these properties, the types don't match. I'd love to understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a type `T` extends your interface, it means that it probably adds some more properties to a base type, or narrows its existing properties. Here are examples of interfaces that conform the `extends Base` condition:

```js
type T1 = {one: number; two: number; three: number};
type T2 = {one: 1; two: 2};
```

If you apply `exampleFunction` to `arg` of type `T1`, it will not return an object of type you have declared: property `three` will be missing. For this particular case you may be looking for some construction like `return {...arg}` – it will keep all properties in place, so Typescript will be satisfied with it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! Wow, I had to read that 10x before it made click. But now I understand it! Thank you!